# How to fix 'IndexError: list index out of range' in python?

Tags: python, list, indexing

I am in year 10 and really bad at coding. Basically I am trying to make a really simple evolution simulator and it has been working well so far but I ran into this error when using lists to define variables. I attached the full code.

```
#************************#
#*  Jadday's Amazing    *#
#* Evolution Simulator  *#
#************************#

import random

print("The Evolution Starts Here")

numcs = 100

def generation1():
    global numcs
    profiles = []
    maxscore = 0
    minscore = 100
    x = 0
    for i in range(0,numcs):
        a = random.randint(0,75)
        b = random.randint(a,100)
        score = random.randint(a,b)
        name = [a,b]
        x = str(x)
        x = int(x)
        x = x + 1

        if score > maxscore:
            maxscore = score
            score = str(score)
            best = score
            score = int(score)

        if score < minscore:
            minscore = score
            score = str(score)
            worst = score
            score = int(score)

        score = str(score)
        profile = score
        score = int(score)
        profiles.append(score)
        profiles = [int(x) for x in profiles]
        profiles.sort()
        print(profile)
    print("")
    print("")
    print("The best was:")
    print(best)
    print("")
    print("The worst was:")
    print(worst)

    numcs = numcs // 2

    templength = len(profiles)
    length = templength // 2

    for x in range(0,length):
        del profiles[0]

    print("")
    print(profiles)



def generation():
    global numcs
    profiles = []
    maxscore = 0
    minscore = 100
    x = 0
    for i in range(0,numcs):
        a = profiles[i]
        a = a / 2
        b = profiles[i]
        b = b * 2
        score = random.randint(a,b)
        name = [a,b]
        x = str(x)
        x = int(x)
        x = x + 1

        if score > maxscore:
            maxscore = score
            score = str(score)
            best = score
            score = int(score)

        if score < minscore:
            minscore = score
            score = str(score)
            worst = score
            score = int(score)

        score = str(score)
        profile = score
        score = int(score)
        profiles.append(score)
        profiles = [int(x) for x in profiles]
        profiles.sort()
        print(profile)
    print("")
    print("")
    print("The best was:")
    print(best)
    print("")
    print("The worst was:")
    print(worst)

    numcs = numcs // 2

    templength = len(profiles)
    length = templength // 2

    for x in range(0,length):
        del profiles[0]

    print("")
    print(profiles)




generation1()
for x in range(0,6):
    generation()
    numcs = numcs // 2
```

The error is in the line 'a = profiles[i]' when defining 'generation'.
I most likely am doing the simulator really inefficiently but I am trying to make it simpler.
If anyone knows how to solve this I would appreciate it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In function `generation1` your `profiles = []` is empty list. In the following line, you try to take `profiles[i]` where `i` ranges from 0 to 100.